# A small program for understanding unions in C

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, unions

```
typedef union{
    int a;  
    char b[10];
    float c;     
} Union;

int main()
{
    Union x,y={100};

    x.a=10;
    strcpy(x.b,"hello");
    x.c=21.50;

    printf("%d\t%s\t%f\n",x.a,x.b,x.c);
    printf("%d\t%s\t%f\n",y.a,y.b,y.c);
    return 0;
}
```

I have this program where I am able to make out all the outputs except for "x.a" and "y.c". Both these outputs are a bit confusing. 
I do know that floats are stored in memory in a different way as compared to int, but still I am unable to make out the possible reasons for the output.

Any help will be appreciated.

The outputs are

```
110792132                21.500000
100           d          0.000000
```

Comment: So what are the outputs you get? What are the outputs you expect to get?

Comment: Is there a specific question in here somewhere.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey - No. There is, in fact, no question at all. All of OP's sentences are statements, none are questions.

Comment: And, the duplicate question will do so - note that searching for a similar answer is far preferable to simply asking each question as it occurs to you.